# error in model laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm doing update for blog data all data has been updated except flag i print all data of request

but the data of flag is'nt updated

here is the code

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    $data=$request->all();
    //dd($request->flag);
    $data       =   $request->except(['_token']);
    $blog=Blog::findOrfail($id);
    $blog->update($data);
    // $blog->update($request->flag);
    dd($data);
        if(request()->hasFile('url_image'))
        {
                    $file=$request['url_image'];
                    $name =md5(uniqid(rand(), true)). $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $request->file('url_image')->move('dezique/images/blog/', $name);
                    $blog->url_image=('dezique/images/blog/'.$name); 
                    $blog->update();
        }
        else
        {
                    $blog->url_image=('dezique/images/blog/cafe.JPEG');
                    $blog->update();
        }

 }
```

ths is the model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $table="blogs";

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'url_image',
            'description',
            'blog_category_id',
            'author_id',
            'flag => string',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            ];
}
```

when i put the flag on $fillable and put this in controller `$blog->update($request->flag);` i got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKR4X.jpg)

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "name" => "fff"
  "blog_category_id" => "2"
  "author_id" => "7"
  "flag" => "show"
  "description" => "hghgjh"
]

Answer (score 0):

update method require array as parameter. you can use `$blog->save()` to update the image

and on your $fillable change `'flag => string'` to `flag`